# Generating repeated iterations of data across two data frames in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to calculate distance between two sets of phonetic variables in R using an established matrix of phonetic measurements. For example, I want to take the measurements for /p/ and the measurements for /b/, and then compare the distance between these two phonetic units. I can do this using the following matrix of distinctive phonetic features:

```
 library(tibble)     
 distinctive.feature.matrix <- tribble(~Symbol, ~Sonorant, ~Consonantal, ~Voice, ~Nasal, 
 ~Degree, ~Labial, ~Palatal, ~Pharyngeal, ~Round, ~Tongue, ~Radical,
                                       "p", -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 
                                       "b", -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 
                                       "t", -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                                       "d", -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                                       "k", -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
                                       "g", -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
                                       "f", -0.5, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                                       "v", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                                       "θ", -0.5, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0,
                                       "ð", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0,
                                       "s", -0.5, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                                       "z", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                                       "h", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1,
                                       "ʃ", -0.5, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0,
                                       "ʒ", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0,
                                       "tʃ", -0.8, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0,
                                       "dʒ", -0.8, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0,
                                       "m", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                                       "n", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                                       "ŋ", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
                                       "r", 0.5, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1,
                                       "l", 0.5, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                                       "w", 0.8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0,
                                       "j", 0.8, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1)
```

I have another set of data showing child productions of different words, and I want to calculate the distance between the child's production and that of the target, for each consonant in the target word.

The production data looks a bit like this:

```
 library(tibble) 
 production.data <- tribble(~Subject, ~Age, ~Target, ~C1_target, ~C1_actual,
      "subj1", "001126", "teddy", "t", "d",
      "subj1", "001126", "teddy", "t", "t",
      "subj1", "001126", "daddy", "d", "d",
      "subj1", "001126", "daddy", "d", "d",
      "subj1", "001126", "daddy", "d", "t",
      "subj1", "001126", "baby", "b", "p",
      "subj1", "001126", "Tigger", "t", "d",
      "subj1", "001126", "doggy", "d", "d",
      "subj1", "001126", "milk", "m", "m")
```

So, for each instance of `production.data$C1_target` I want to take the values of the corresponding consonant in `distinctive.feature.matrix` and compare them with the values of `productiondata$C1_actual`. Once I have these values, I will subtract the `C1_actual` value from the `C1_target` value, across each of the 11 distinctive features.

By way of example, for the first instance of 'teddy', I want to compare /t/ with /d/, which means subtracting -1 from -1 (`distinctive.feature.matrix$Sonorant`), 1 from 1 (`distinctive.feature.matrix$Consonantal`), 0 from -1 (`distinctive.feature.matrix$Voice`), etc. I'll then do some further calculations on these, but I'll leave it as this for now as it's already quite complicated.

I think I can use `for loops` to do this but I haven't used this function before and no amount of searching brings up a usable example.

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr package provides join functions that can help.

For every row of the production.data, you can bring in the corresponding features for each C1_target, C1_actual to create a large tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- production.data %>% 
     inner_join(distinctive.feature.matrix, by = c("C1_target"="Symbol")) %>%
     inner_join(distinctive.feature.matrix, by = c("C1_actual"="Symbol"))
```

Note that there are two calls to inner_join: one to get features corresponding to C1_target, the second for features for C1_actual

The new tibble has column names such as Sonorant.x and Sonorant.y, the first corresponding to C1_target and the second corresponding to C1_actual.

You can create a list of feature names by taking the column names, excluding Symbol:

```
features <- colnames(distinctive.feature.matrix)[-1]
```

Now you can do your 'for-loop' to calculate the difference between the x and y values, and then combine the lot into a new data frame:

```
diffs <- do.call(cbind, sapply(features, function(f) x[paste0(f, '.x')] - x[paste0(f, '.y')]))
colnames(diffs) <- features
```

The paste0 function concatenates each feature name with .x or .y; the sapply is the equivalent of the for-loop; and the cbind bashes the result of each computation into a new table.

You will end up with a data frame whose column names are the features, and as many rows as your production.data had.

To be fair, the above code is an ugly confection of dplyr-like syntax and base R...

Comment: Thank you! One problem here (which I didn't specify in my Q) is that I'll also need to conserve the `C1_Target` and `C1_Actual` columns. At this point the data looks a bit weird (there are too many 0s when I use my full dataset) but I can't tell where the problem is because I can't see which row is which. But thank you - this is definitely getting there!